# Error: expected template-name before '<' token, C++?

Tags: c++

going to go ahead and say this is homework. I'm trying to compile a program that uses virtual functions, and templates. However I'm getting the error:

> Error: Expected template-name before '<' token 
>   struct compareItem : binary_function{
>
> error: expected '{' before '<' token
>   error: expected unqualified-id before '<' token

This is the main.C

```
#include "Item.h"
int main(){
    priority_queue<Item*, vector<Item*>, compareItem> pq;
    W* w = new W(0, &pq);
    T* t = new T(10, &pq);
    pq.push(w);
    pq.push(t);
    while(!pq.empty()){
       Item* i = pq.top();
       pq.pop();
       i->Run();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

this is the Item.h

```
#ifndef ITEM_H
#define ITEM_H
#include <functional>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Item{
   int key;
public:
   Item(int k) : key (k){}
   friend class compareItem;
   int getKey() {return key;}
   void setkey(int x) {key = x;}
   virtual void Run(){}
   virtual ~Item(){}
};

struct compareItem : binary_function<Item*, Item*, bool>{
    bool operator()(const Item* t1, const Item* t2) const{
        return (t1->key > t2->key);
    }
};

class W : public Item{
    priority_queue<Item*, vector<Item*>, compareItem>* q;
    public:
    W(int k, priority_queue<Item*, vector<Item*>, compareItem >* q1) : Item (k), q(q1){}
    void Run() {cout << "W at " << getKey() << endl;
                setKey(getKey()+10);
                q->push(this);
    ~W(){}
};

class T : public Item{
    priority_queue<Item*, vector<Item*>, compareItem >* 1;
    public:
    T(int k, priority_queue<Item*, vector<Item*>, compareItem >* q1) : Item (k), q(q1){}
    void Run() {cout << "T at " << getKey() << endl;
                setKey(getKey()+25);
                q->push(this);
    ~T(){}
};

#endif
```

Comment: Try `std::binary_function`.

Comment: have you tried using `std::vector`?

Comment: I decided to add 'using namespace std;' in and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: [Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: I'd also like to add `using namespace std` is a bad habit to get into.

Comment: It might seem like a hassle, but before you know it, you'll be typing `std::` without even thinking about it.  It will not slow you down at all.